# Получить текст внутри следующих тегов

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Сервер выдаёт ответ со следующей разметкой

```
<p class="hvl-post-author">
    <a href="https://example.com" title="Источник" target="_blank">
    site our</a>(site our)
  <span class="hvl-post-author-separ">→</span>
</p>
```

как получить текст внутри тега а

```
 preg_match_all('#<p class="hvl-post-author"><a(.?)+>(.+?)</a>#is', $arr);
      print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [HTML-парсер](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) для этого, регулярки не подходят для этого:

```
$str = <<<HTML_CODE
<p class="hvl-post-author">
    <a href="https://example.com" title="Источник" target="_blank">
    site our</a>(site our)
  <span class="hvl-post-author-separ">→</span>
</p>
HTML_CODE;
$html = str_get_html($str);
var_dump($html->find('a', 0)->innertext); // site our
```

Comment: А почему регулярки не подходят?

Comment: @Bookin, регулярные выражения не подходят для языков. Конструкция может поменяться, выполняя одно и то же, а регулярка сломается.

Comment: ну если разметка измениться то и любой код, привязанный к ней, поломается, хоть это регулярка, хоть парсер.

Answer (score 1):

Конкретно в вашем примере:

- `preg_match_all` принимает три параметра `preg_match_all(шаблон, где ищем, куда сохраним результат)`
- в вашей регулярке между тегами `<p>` и `<а>` не должно быть никаких символов, в тексте же как минимум перенос строки

Даже ваш вариант регулярного выражение будет работать если учесть эти два пункта

`preg_match_all('#<p class="hvl-post-author">.*<a(.?)+>(.+?)</a>#is', $str, $arr);`

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d72b36fb2fd2a2522648c15ee8dfb24be2583b11